# Data Binding not working for textView while using some function

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, data-binding

First I have declared the variables in the layout file

```
    <data>
  
    <variable
        name="signUpViewModel"
        type="ac.connect.ui.signup.SignUpViewModel" />
</data>
```

Now I'm trying to use a function of StringExtension class which takes string value as parameter and to set the result to textView

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#C1BDBD"
    android:textColor="#3D3C3C"
    app:capitalizeFirstLetter="@{signUpViewModel.name}" />
```

**capitalize First Letter function**

```
  fun capitalizeFirstLetter(value: String): String {
    var ans = ""
    val words = value.split(" ")

    words.forEach {
        ans += it.capitalize() + " "
    }


    return ans
}
```

ViewModel

```
  class SignUpViewModel(private val setProfileUseCase: SetProfileUseCase) :    
 ViewModel() {


private val _profile = MutableLiveData<ProfileModel>()
val profile: LiveData<ProfileModel>
    get() = _profile

private val _name = MutableLiveData<String>()
val name: LiveData<String>
    get() = _name


fun setName(name: Editable) {
    _name.value = name.toString()

}


fun setProfileData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val profile = ProfileModel(
                name = "kamal nayan",
                branch = "CSE",
                gender = "Male",
                mobileNumber = "+91-73555555517",
                rollNo = "GCS/345353",
                uid = "ghafagaraggGGG"

        )
        val response = setProfileUseCase.invoke(profile)
        _profile.value =  profile
        response.successOrError(::handleProductDetailsSuccess, ::handleSignUpFailure)
    }


}

private fun handleProductDetailsSuccess(response: Boolean) {
    _name.value = "User Data Uploaded Successfully"

}

private fun handleSignUpFailure(failure: Failure, error: ErrorResponse?) {
    Timber.log(Log.ERROR, error?.message)
}
  }
```

Fragment Code:

```
class SignUpFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_sign_up) {

    private val viewModel: SignUpViewModel by viewModel()
    private var binding by autoCleared<FragmentSignUpBinding>()


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding = FragmentSignUpBinding.bind(view)
        binding.signUpViewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.signUp.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.setProfileData()
        }

    }


    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): SignUpFragment {
            return SignUpFragment()
        }
    }
}
```

The output is blank , like no text in the textView

Kindly help me with this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your ViewModel and Fragment/Activity

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Posted both.

Comment: `StringExtensions` is a class or an object?

Comment: It's a function and recently I updated the question and now we don't need to make variable .... made a binding adapter .... but how to observe live data from layout

Comment: Check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are not setting the value of the variable `stringExtensions` when setting up your `DataBinding`

```
import ac.connect.utils.StringExtensions

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding = FragmentSignUpBinding.bind(view)
    binding.signUpViewModel = viewModel
    // binding.stringExtensions = StringExtensions() // If it is a class
    // binding.stringExtensions = StringExtensions // If it is an object
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

    binding.signUp.setOnClickListener {
        viewModel.setProfileData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you need make `BindingAdapter`. So you need rewrite your 'capitalizeFirstLetter' function as below.

```
 @BindingAdapter("app:capitalizeFirstLetter")
 @JvmStatic fun capitalizeFirstLetter(textView: TextView, value: String){
    var ans = ""
    val words = value.split(" ")

    words.forEach {
        ans += it.capitalize() + " "
    }
    textView.setText(ans)
}
```

Also I didn't see where you call `setName` function. Are you sure that `_name.value` is not empty?

Comment: it is a LiveData so how to observe this in layout........ like if it's null then we need to set something and if it's loaded we will set its value.

Comment: Are you make BindingAdapter for your TextView as I say in my answer? For your comment: you can set breakpoint in your `setValue` function. So you can see is it call at all. Also you can set breakpoint in `capitalizeFirstLetter` function to see value wich transmitted there.